# Any latest gem of react-router for rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router, react-rails, react-routing

I am using `rails4` with `react-rails` gem and there is a gem for react-router is https://github.com/mariopeixoto/react-router-rails but this is using too old version of `react-router (0.13)` and currently `react-router-2` has been launched.

So is there any other ruby gems that support `react-router-2`

Comment: Please let me know the reason if you down vote for this question

Comment: What would the gem do that the npm module couldn't?

Comment: @azium I am getting to many error while adding this npm module into rails , This is configuration issue with rails